# html2canvas missing image on transform scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.9, and using jsplumbtoolkit to display Layout. I want save html on screen layout to image pnj file. But I have an bug when zoom in, zoom out html.
My code like this:

```
function PreviewPrinter() {
    $("#previewImage").html('');
    var cvs = document.getElementById('jsPlumb_2_1');
    html2canvas(cvs).then(function (canvas) {
        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $("#previewImage").html("<img src=" + myImage + ">");
    });
    ShowModal("printView");
}
```

But I have an error like below:
When I zoom in with `transform: scale(0.306108);` and drag 1 image out of position, this image will missing when I append to Canvas. 
I have image example below, fist image I drag out of position.
Image I want to save file .PNJ
[image]

Image error when append to canvas, you can see the first image is missing

[image]